# ubuntu 12.04 acer display not proper 16:9

Tags: nvidia, 12.04, acer

I try to install ubuntu 12.04 lts edition on acer latptop 4752G with core i5 and geforce 610m 1 gb video driver.
But when i try for additional hard ware , no nvdia driver is loaded there.
What could be the issue . I am not getting 16:9 resolution.
Could you please help
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final release is April 26th. The kernel freeze is 5th. You might get lucky after the 5th an update. That may take care of your issues.

Currently 12.04 is a beta release. Use it as is.

Comment: Yes i install current beta version with all the updates .. still not luck .. i will wait for 5th for updates for ubuntu 12.04 . apart from display 16:9 everything cool ..